# Activate div when another one is done

Tags: jquery

What I'm trying to achieve is that when I press a button, a vertical line appears that starts at one point and end after a (random)px. That is working.

When that event is done I want a circle to appear below it, it's kinda working except that the circle appears as soon as I press the button and not when the vertical line is fully loaded.

For clarification, I want the circle to appear when the vertical line is at its end. Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.name-box').click(function(){
    $('.verti-line').animate({ height: '220px' }, 2000 );
    $('.circle').show();
});
```

});

Best regards, Viktor!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.name-box').click(function(){
    $('.verti-line').animate({ height: '220px' }, 2000, function(){
        $('.circle').show();
    });
});
```

You can pass a function as a parameter to use as a callback. This will run the circle show method when the animation is complete.

Answer (score 0):

animate have a `complete` function. To call it, you just have to write that :

```
$('.verti-line').animate({ height: '220px' }, {duration : 2000, complete : function(){$('.circle').show();}});
```

When the animation is done, the circle will show!

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery docs for animate, http://api.jquery.com/animate/.  So something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.name-box').click(function(){
    $('.verti-line').animate({ height: '220px' }, 2000, function() {
        $('.circle').show();
    });
});
```